# position() and tables

Tags: jquery

How can it be that this doesn't alert `0` (instead, it alerts `50`)?

I need the td position relative to the table

http://jsfiddle.net/vxVCE/

HTML:

```
<div style="height:40px"></div>
<div>
    <table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <td id="td1">linje 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td2">linje 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var elm = $('#td1');
var position = elm.position();
alert(position.top);
```

edit:
I need the tr position relative to the table :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the table. Doing that will make it alert 0. Otherwise, it's finding position relative to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is **not** at the top -- therefore it is **not** zero

---

The body has a padding of `10px`.
The div above the table is `40px` in height.

Therefore it alerts "`50`" (`10 + 40 = 50`)

Answer (score 1):

@Neal has explained beautifully why it gives 50. Here's the second part:

To get the position w.r.t the to table, subtract table's top from the `td` top:

```
alert(position.top - $('#td1').closest('table').position().top);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/vxVCE/1/

*Note:* Depending on your HTML/CSS, you might have to use table's `offset` instead.

```
alert(position.top - $('#td1').closest('table').offset().top);
```

Comment: that seems complicated for no reason. also it does not explain why it alerts `50` in the OP's example.

Comment: @Neal: It may be complicated (arguably though), but it is what you need if you want to get the `td` position relative to table's viewport. And you already explained nicely why it gives 50, din't wanna repeat the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the position relative to the `table` you will also need to add it to the `tbody` if you have one