# jquery .position() returns .offset() in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a table with a head and body and I would like to get back the position of a specific row with respect to the top of the table body.  I have set the **tbody** of the table to position:relative and am using the **$.position()** method to read back position.  This works as I expect in Firefox, but Chrome seems to ignore the offset parent and return relative to the entire document.  See below and http://jsfiddle.net/CmMz8/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>header</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="test"><td>row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Position: <span id="pos"></span> Offset: <span id="off"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
tbody {
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
var pos = $('#test').position().top;
var off = $('#test').offset().top;
$('#pos').text(pos);
$('#off').text(off);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [position() and tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083133/position-and-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to position the table, not the tbody:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/CmMz8/3

```
table {position: relative;}
```

See also **[position() and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083133/position-and-tables)**

Comment: That did it!  If I subtract the position of the first row, then I get back what I was looking for.  It's not clear to me why I can't set `position:relative` to the tbody, but it clearly doesn't work in Chrome.